# Can a person with dutch residence permit drive with non-eu driving license in Belgium?

Tags: driving-licenses, belgium

I have been living in the Netherlands for more than 6 months but I still haven't changed my driving license from Malaysia(with English writing on it), which is still valid. Now I can't driving in the Netherlands anymore with this license.

However can I drive in Belgium with this license, even though I've been in EU for more than 6 months?

Comment: I suspect that you can, but I do not know.

Comment: "Living in the Netherlands" sounds very much like something that belongs on our sister site [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Check carefully.  I cannot speak for Belgium and the Netherlands but it is common that the rules for visitors and residents are not the same.  For example, even if a visitor could use their licence for a year, the limit might be less for a resident.

Comment: I believe this question has been put on hold wrongly. This is about traveling to Belgium and driving there for a short time. It's not about immigration or moving anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to this webpage from the Belgian federal governement, a Malaysian drivers license is valid in Belgium : https://mobilit.belgium.be/nl/wegverkeer/rijbewijs/vreemde_rijbewijzen/niet_europese_rijbewijzen

Comment: And being a resident in the Netherlands does not stop that.